# How to set constraints based on screen size in Xcode using Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to be able to have my constraints, `UIImages`, and `UIButtons` to be proportionate to all screen. How do I do that? Like on the iPad, lets say its 137p x 60p and lets say the iPhone's width is 150% smaller and the height is lets say is 125% smaller. I want it to scale the position and size by 150% down/horizontal and 125% side/vertical
(I know its actually not those sizes but hypothetically.)

Comment: you can always use size classes...

Comment: Use the constraint's "multiplier" (or multiplier plus constant) to set the size/position as a multiple of the super view's relevant constraint. Or, as Nick suggests, if you have significantly different layout for different sized devices, using size classes.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to create constraints in relation to the size of the current device's screen.

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

// This constraint makes the view's width equal to half that of the screen
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: /* first view */, 
    attribute: .width,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: nil, 
    attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: width/2)

// Same for height
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: /* first view */, 
    attribute: .height,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: nil, 
    attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: height/2)
```

Answer (score -2):

use equal height and equal width to screen and then play with multiplier to change the position and width and height of what ever you want.